# Is there a way to conditionally validate a model based on the http verb used?

Tags: .net-core-2.2

I'm writing an API and have a very simple model

```cpp
public class CategoryModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I don't want to enforce that the `ID` property is required if the model is coming in via a `post` action, but I do if it's a `put` action. Are there any validation attributes that allow for this or do I need to create a separate model for `post` and `put`?

I'm just learning this so I could be doing it wrong altogether so a point in the right direction would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can do by use fluentvalidation library or create customer attribute